# Genesis 4:7 Timshol-bo

Tags: hebrew, commentaries, parashat-bereishit, translation

The verse of [Genesis 4:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0104.htm#7) ends with the words תמשל-בו (timshol-bo), and is often translated as 'you shall rule over it'.

But the prefix Bet often means 'in', 'with', 'at' or 'on'. Maybe there some other meanings that fit with the prefix Bet, but I wondered why the word בו is translated as 'over it', does the letter bet as a prefix also carries the meaning 'over' ?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Hebrew grammar question than anything else, but there are at least ten different meanings that this particular particle (represented by the letter, *bet*) might have:

1) Spatial - ie: "in", "at", or "on" a place. For example, Genesis 31:54 - ויזבח יעקב זבח בהר ("Then Jacob offered a sacrifice *on* the mountain");

2) Temporal - ie: a point in time when an action takes place. For example, Genesis 30:14 - בימי קציר חטים ("*in* the days of wheat harvest");

3) Instrumental - ie: an inanimate object used to perform an action. For example, Exodus 22:23 - והרגתי אתכם בחרב ("and I will kill you *with* the sword");

4) Adversative - ie: a relationship of disadvantage. For example, Genesis 16:12 - ידו בכל ויד כל בו ("his hand will be *against* everyone and everyone's hand *against* him");

5) Specification - ie: clarifying an immediately preceding action. For example, Genesis 7:21 - ויגוע כל בשר הרמש על הארץ בעוף ובבהמה ובחיה ובכל השרץ ("and all flesh died that moved on the earth - birds, cattle, wild animals, all swarming creatures");

6) Causal - ie: a cause or reason for something. For example, Deuteronomy 24:16 - איש בחטאו יומתו ("each person shall be put to death *because of* his own sin");

7) Accompaniment - ie: denoting circumstances that occur together with something else. For example, Genesis 39:9 - באשר את אשתו ("*because* you are his wife");

8) Essence - ie: marking the identity of a noun. For example, Genesis 1:26 - נעשה אדם בצלמנו ("let us make man *in* our image");

9) Manner - ie: as an adverb, describing the way that an action is performed. For example, לך בשלום ("go *peaceably*");

10) Price - ie: indicating the cost of something. For example, Genesis 23:9 - בכסף מלא יתננה לי ("let him give it to me *at the cost of* full silver").

For more information, see Bill T. Arnold and John H. Choi, *A Guide to Biblical Hebrew Syntax* (Cambridge University Press, 2003), 102-106.

Your example (תמשול־בו), is like #4 above: an adversative use of the particle. Such usages are common, and are found throughout Tanakh.

Comment: Just checking if I got your answer correctly: would you translate timshol bo in Bereshit 4:7 as: but you can rule 'against' it?

Comment: @levi, You can look at any published translation to see how people translate it. It's not particularly ambiguous. I would translate it as "rule over it", but that doesn't mean that the Hebrew particle has the same semantic range as the English "over". Languages don't work like that.

Comment: I understand that, but the meaning of 'rule over' is something else as 'rule with' or 'rule against'. So I do think it's important to understand the suffix בו in relation to תמשול, which meaning is also not so clear as crystal for Hirsch and Vilna Gaon (to name some) both give a different definition to it. I'm just trying to understand these two little words and the meaning (in the broadest sense) they have when used combined.

Answer (score 0):

I will first show how Rav Hirsch explains the meaning of *תמשול בו* and then contrast it with תמלך על to show the difference between them and the reason for it. I will also explain the reason for the particular pasuk that you reference.

Rav Hirsch translates *תמשול בו* as *master it*, he then explains that

> So that in truth the relationship between Man and his passions should
>   be essentially not unlike that between husband and wife. A Man should
>   be freely affianced to his sensuality, so as, under his guidance,
>   together with it, to achieve the highest purpose of life.

Note what Hashem tells Chava in [Bereishis 3:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167/jewish/Chapter-3.htm#v=16&showrashi=true)

> אֶל־הָֽאִשָּׁ֣ה אָמַ֗ר הַרְבָּ֤ה אַרְבֶּה֙ עִצְּבוֹנֵ֣ךְ וְהֵֽרֹנֵ֔ךְ
>   בְּעֶ֖צֶב תֵּֽלְדִ֣י בָנִ֑ים וְאֶל־אִישֵׁךְ֙ תְּשׁ֣וּקָתֵ֔ךְ וְה֖וּא
>   יִמְשָׁל־בָּֽךְ:
>
> To the woman He said, "I shall surely increase your sorrow and your
>   pregnancy; in pain you shall bear children. And to your husband will
>   be your desire, and he will rule over you."

Rav Hirsch also connects this with משל.

> basic meaning: to declare what something is and should be, to give its
>   character and designation. Hence, to command, to rule. The משל
>   directs everyone what he is to be and do. So that it is by no means
>   synonymous with כבש, to force to subjugate, it is rather to guide and
>   rule.

Thus one establishes the correct character and meaning of a relationship **within** the party being *ruled*. This usage is why the בו is used here as well as why בָּֽךְ is used with Chava.

Note that in [Vayeishev 37:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8232#v=8&showrashi=true) the two terms are contrasted.

> וַיֹּ֤אמְרוּ לוֹ֙ אֶחָ֔יו הֲמָלֹ֤ךְ תִּמְלֹךְ֙ עָלֵ֔ינוּ אִם־מָשׁ֥וֹל
>   תִּמְשֹׁ֖ל בָּ֑נוּ וַיּוֹסִ֤פוּ עוֹד֙ שְׂנֹ֣א אֹת֔וֹ עַל־חֲלֹֽמֹתָ֖יו
>   וְעַל־דְּבָרָֽיו:
>
> So his brothers said to him, "Will you reign over us, or will you
>   govern us?" And they continued further to hate him on account of his
>   dreams and on account of his words.

Rav Hirsch translates the two terms for ruling as

> Wouldst thou indeed be a King over us, or indeed now rule over us

The first term, מלך על, implies the force of כבוש over one imposed from outside, while the term משול ב means have us accept you as the ruler internally so that you are the *legitimate* and accepted ruler. This is the difference in modern terms between the dictator of North Korea, or the mullahs of Iran and the President of the United States or the Queen of England.

Comment: This doesn't answer any part of the question, which was about the prefix + pronoun, בו

Comment: @ShimonbM The last sentence explains why the  בו is used with the   משל I first needed to explain the main usage beforesaying why that pronoun

Comment: I still don't understand why it says bo, which can be found in many verses about 'ruling', but most often means 'among', why not use al על like in Genesis 37:8 to give it the meaning of 'over', it (almost) seems that the verse here teaches that man has to rule with or (among).

Comment: @Levi Exactly. It is not ruling **over** which is the context of , to force to subjugate but is the context of ruling within. I will add the reference to 37:8 to show the difference.

Comment: @Levi Did the section that I added explain what I meant more precisely. Thank you for the reference as I used that to show why the two terms differ.

Comment: Found this at: http://www.jewishanswers.org. "There are two words for “rule” in Hebrew: “Melech” and “Moshel”. The Vilna Gaon writes in his commentary that” Melech” means a king who rules with the consent of the governed, but a “Moshel” is a dictator: He rules by force." This seems kind of the opposite of what Hirsch says? How come their so different in defining these terms?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpfull I needthe link to the actual question and answer that you refer to so that I can see what it says.

Comment: http://www.jewishanswers.org/ask-the-rabbi-category/womens-issues/?p=2028

Comment: P.s. Looking at Bereshit 37:8 and the question what the difference is between to 'timloch' and 'timshol' - Ibn Ezra explains that the former implies that “we will place you over us as a king” while the latter means that “you will dominate us by force.” Jewish kings were never intended to rule by force. Rather, as the verse in Deuteronomy states, “You shall place a king over you” (17:15). Our leaders, who were always chosen with the assent of the people, worked to further the nation’s needs and interests.

Comment: The Vilna Gaon teaches that the word Melech means King; who is willfully accepted by his subjects. The word Moshel means ruler by force. What came out of the mouths' of the Shevatim was as follows, "HaMaloch Timloch Aleinu?" will you ever be king (Melech) over us? No of course not because we will never accept you. "Im Mashol Timshol Banu" If you do rule over us, your power will be by brute force and you will be a Moshel over us.

Comment: The quotes I gave show the opposite of what you proposed in your answer, I would like to know how I should view these differences, cause I liked your given interpretation a lot, but these quotes confuse me.

Comment: besides words like ממשלה, מושל מושלת, ממשל don't seem to denote rulers by force

Comment: @sabbahillel if you're able please read my connents, looking forward to read your answer on it.

Comment: @Levi I just pointed out what Rav Hirsch had to say about the idea of using the bais as opposed to al. Apparently, the idea is that of internalizing the rulership as opposed to regarding it as external but on oneself. Perhaps, one can use the difference in the other way, That is melech on being accepted as a position as opposed to *mashal b* ruling imposed on the internal thoughts. However, that does not appear to be what Rav Hirsch says. I will look at it again.

Comment: @sabbahillel that would be great, I wonder if they just oppose a different view on the matter or if they are somehow combineable.

Answer (score 0):

R' Yehudah ibn Tibbon, one of the great translators, laid out the rules for translating in the preface to his translation of [Chovos Halevavos](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41644&st=&pgnum=5&hilite=). The translator must

- know the language of the original book
- The language he is translating into
- and understand the content

This way, he can adapt from one language to another without creating confusion by being excessively literal (like Amelia Bedelia). For [example](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.14.8?ven=The_Rashi_chumash_by_Rabbi_Shraga_Silverstein&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Onkelos_Exodus.14.8&lang2=bi), the Bible says the Jews left Egypt with "יד רמה/a high hand" but Onkelos translates it as "ריש גלי/ an uncovered head", because that was the proper expression in Aramaic.

So in this case, while the hebrew preposition ב which means "in" or "with" is appropriate with the root word "משל/rule", in English the proper word expression is "rule *over*", and that is just a stylistic difference between the two languages.